# Can't prevent showing the automatic PWA install prompt?

Tags: single-page-application, progressive-web-apps

My goal is take over the "beforeinstallprompt" event, and only show it once the user taps on a button.

So per [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/onbeforeinstallprompt), I'm catching the event like so:

```
  window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //save the event for later
  });
```

However, the prompt still shows up on itself as if I never called `e.preventDefault()`.

So what's going on here?

Comment: Does `beforeinstallprompt` ever get fired (add some logging/a breakpoint to check)? I'm assuming you're seeing this with Chrome—which version are you using?

Comment: If you are not using Chrome, try using a normal anonymous function rather than an arrow function on the listener and add a console.log after preventDefault() to make sure the listener is attached

Comment: @Birowsky I am facing the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @ArkaGhosh no. sorry.